# User.find is ignoring method to_param

Tags: activerecord, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-3.1

I have a `User` model witch i have override the `to_param` method.

i made it like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_param
    if self.id < 100
      if self.id < 10
        s = "00#{self.id}"
      else
        s = "0#{self.id}"
      end
    else
      s = "#{self.id}"
    end
    return "usr-#{s}"
  end

end
```

And on my controller:

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
@title = user.name
```

the problem is... i can`t get any users...

if i change the `to_param` method to: `return "#{s}-usr"` it simple ignores the `-usr` and search for the id without taking `-usr`

i already tried an after_save filter, but i could`n change an atribute on there.

how can i create an unique id to an user based on his id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails won't do inverse transformation for you, you have to do it yourself. I think you can do it like that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Returns formatted user id:
  #
  #   1    => 'usr-001'
  #   11   => 'usr-011'
  #   111  => 'usr-111'
  #   1111 => 'usr-1111'      
  #
  def to_param
    "usr-%03d" % id
  end 

  def self.from_param(param)
    # ruby strips leading zeros for us (e.g., '012'.to_i returns 12)
    # but we need to remove 'usr-' prefix first
    find(param[4..-1].to_i)
  end 

end
```

and then use it in wherever you need it:

```
user = User.from_param params[:id]
```

In addition, have a look at `to_param` [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param). Description and examples clearly state that this method is used for generating urls, but developer is the one responsible for finding corresponding record by this parameter.

Regarding strings formatting you can find more info in docs for [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25) method and [`Kernel#format`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) method it uses.

Comment: i`ve tried this, but in my controler is returning this error: ``undefined method `from_param' for #<Class:0x00000102b63bd8>``

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: `from_param` should be a class method. I updated the code.